# All possible solutions to the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to list all possible solutions to the following differential equation?

\begin{equation}
3f^{'}(x) ^2 = 2f(x)f^{''}(x)
\end{equation}

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I know one solution: $f(x) = -(1-x)^{-1}$

Comment: So you're asking for the general solution then?  The phrasing on the question is strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First dividing by $f'$ and $f$ gives
$$
3\frac{f'}{f}=2\frac{f''}{f'}.
$$
Integrating,
$$
3\log f=2\log f'+\log C=\log Cf'^2
$$
and hence
$$
f^3=Cf'^2.
$$
This can be written
$$
\frac{f'}{f^{3/2}}=D,
$$
which is again separable,
$$
\frac{-2}{f^{1/2}}=Dx+E.
$$
Turning things around, you find that $f$ can be written in the form
$$
f=\frac{c_1}{(x+c_2)^2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

you can rewrite the differential equation $3f'^2 = 2ff''$ as $$ 2\frac {f''} {f'} =  3\frac{f'}f$$ on integration yield $$f'^2 = C^2f^3  \to \frac{df}{dx} = \pm Cf^{3/2}$$ we can separate this $$f^{-3/2} \,df  = \pm Cdx $$
on integration gives
$$ B \pm Cx = \int f^{-3/2} df = -2f^{-1/2}$$ an implicit relation between $x$ and $f.$

Comment: How did you arrive at the last equation? Can you expand it?

Comment: @user2808118, i will edit my answer.

Comment: You made a small mistake on the integration.  You exponentiated both sides before considering the constant of integration.

Comment: @Mike.   thanks.  that is not a small mistake.